# Predictive Content in Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I once saw a Marketing Cloud demo where they had the Attribute View (see screenshot) from Marketing Cloud Contacts within Sales Cloud Lead record view. I can't find anything in AppExchange, so I'm wondering if this was a custom developed view?

[image: Attributes-Tab in Lead record]

Comment: Was a safe harbour statement shown at the beginning of the demo?

Comment: Yes I guess so.

Comment: Mmmm. Well, it's pretty feasible with a visuaforce page, an undocumented SFMC API and a bit of creativity. Do you have any decent CRM Developers to hand?